# IIS complaining about Identity Impersonation using LDAP Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, .net-4.0, ldap

I followed a tutorial to implement LDAP authentication in an ASP.NET/C# 4.0 web application. I did so in Visual Studio 2010. The site runs fine in debug mode through Visual Studio, but when I publish this site in IIS7, it is failing with the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been
>   detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

In fact, part of the tutorial required that I add this to the config file...

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

So why would I be getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: See the explanation at: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try changing your application pool's pipeline mode to 'Classic'.

You do this by opening IIS -> Application Pools -> Right-click your application pool and select Basic Settings -> Managed pipeline mode, change to `Classic`

You may need to restart your app pool and site and try again.

Another thing you can try, instead of the above, is to put the following in your `web.config` file, inside the `<system.webServer>` node:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```